# UIWebView won't fill screen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

**Edit:** This was a result of my own stupidity - the website I was liking to (iphone optimised) was not resizing to take advantage of the extra space, other pages display full screen.

Hi,

I've been trying to create a view that has no navigation bar, just a UIWebView that takes up the entire screen with a button to exit the view. I've managed to find a solution to hiding the navigation bar, but the problem is, it leaves a 44px space at the bottom of the view. So what I have is a webview taking up 460px on the screen, then just a white area below.

In Interface builder I tried to edit the size of the view but it was greyed out and set to 460px. Is there a way to make it so the webview takes up all 480px?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Chris

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your IB window, and what the result is when you're running the app? I think I know what you mean, but before I post an answer, I want to see what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Aurum Aquila, you helped me already! I just changed the URL to google.com to take a screenshot, and it displays full screen. It turns out it's the custom image gallery I'm using (a web one) which does not resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the size of UIVewView programmatically in this way:

myWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

and place it by example in viewDidLoad method.